# WordML list issue

Tags: ms-word, wordml

i need to convert from a HTML-like xml format to WordML. I have a problem with the lists. Word lists are simply paragraphs that contain list properties, typically a reference to a list. The list starts automatically with 1 or A on a new paragraph containing list properties, and the numbering continues with the next paragraph if it has the same list properties.
The problem starts when a single list item contains multiple paragraphs. For example:

```
<li>
  <-- multiple paragraphs -->
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</li>
<li>
  ...
</li>
```

After i inserted all nested paragraphs in list item 1, i wish to continue the numbering in list item 2. But a new list is created starting at 1, because the previous paragraph isn't a list item.
I cannot use the WordML `<w:br/>` tag because of some reasons.
Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot, this will really help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See generally [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee922775(office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee922775%28office.14%29.aspx) for an intro to numbering.

You can continue the previous list.

Comment: Sorry for not responding until now. A great article, but i cannot find how to continue a previous list. Could you guide me more specific or give me a link to your source. Thanks.